# Get shape of both tensor and np array

Tags: numpy, pytorch, numpy-ndarray, tensor, np

Tensor and numpy arrays are pretty similar in use. I'm writing a function that can except either but I need to find a way to get the shape of both a tensor and a np array with the same call. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found you can use '.shape' for both:

```
myNpArray = np.zeros((1,10,256))
print(myNpArray.shape)

myTensor = torch.zeros((1, 10, 256))
print(myTensor.shape)
```

prints

```
(1, 10, 256)
torch.Size([1, 10, 256])
```

Both can be accessed element wise